# How to solve second order linear ODE with variable coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $t^4\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2t^3\frac{dx}{dt}+x=0$ with $x(\pi/2)=0$? I know that the solution is $x(t)=c_1\sin(1/t)$ but I don't know the way to find it.

Answer (score 1):

here is enough theory for you that can solve this problem by yourself
http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) to solve your problem.